# javascript function to get list of objects and return new key with new value in new array

Tags: javascript

for privacy I explain simple example .  function that get personal list and return new key with new
value like below:

```
personalList = [{
        firstName: "elena",
        lastName: "zakharova"
    },
    {
        firstName: "alex",
        lastName: "farmanda"
    },
    {
        firstName: "mike",
        lastName: "kenan"
    }]
```

**output should be like this:**

```
desiredList =[{fullname :'elena zakhrova'},{fullname :'alex farmanda'}, fullname : 'mike kenan']
```

tried some ways but unfortunately did not get answer

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: `personalList.map(({ firstName, lastName }) => ({ fullname: [firstName, lastName].join(" ") }))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use map

```js
const personalList = [{
        firstName: "elena",
        lastName: "zakharova"
    },
    {
        firstName: "alex",
        lastName: "farmanda"
    },
    {
        firstName: "mike",
        lastName: "kenan"
    }]
    
    
console.log(personalList.map(({firstName,lastName}) => ({fullName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`})))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's How I Would Solve This Using For Loop. You Can Also Use Maps Like How @R4ncid Has Explained

```js
var desiredlist = []
var personalList = [{
        firstName: "elena",
        lastName: "zakharova"
    },
    {
        firstName: "alex",
        lastName: "farmanda"
    },
    {
        firstName: "mike",
        lastName: "kenan"
    }]

for (i=0;i<personalList.length;i++){
        desiredlist.push({"fullname":personalList[i].firstName + " " + personalList[i].lastName})}
console.log(desiredlist)
```